# Zooming in UIImageView or UIScrollView?

Tags: uiimageview, zooming, pinchzoom

I just don't understand it.
Could maybe someone post the WHOLE .h AND .m file so I don't have to add single pieces which create thousands of errors?
that would be great .

I already searched through many links and questions but that did not help me.

So what I want is:
I have a picture which is supposed to be a map and i want the user to zoom in and out the map with the normal pinch-gesture.

Thanks for answers.